# Scraping advertisements from a web page using python

Tags: python

How can I scrape ads (e.g Banners) from a dynamically loaded web page - like AdblockPlus - using Python?

I want to exclude ads from a web page to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to scrape webpage.

You need to install the package and just import it

Like this `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: I am currently trying selenium, BeautifulSoup but it scraps only static content and misses the dynamic one.